# erro em função recursiva em c++

Tags: c++, funções, recursão

Essa função recursiva deveria calcular a multiplicação de dois inteiros mas esta retornando sempre +1 no resultado, alguém pode me ajudar?

```
int multiplic(int m1, int m2){
    if(m2==0){
        return 1;
    }
    return m1 + multiplic(m1,m2-1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que no fim da recursão você retorna `1` em vez de retornar `0` e esse `1` é acrescentado no valor da conta.

Basta trocar para `0`:

```
int multiplic(int m1, int m2){
    if(m2==0){
        return 0; // <--
    }
    return m1 + multiplic(m1,m2-1);
}
```

[Veja a correr no Ideone](https://ideone.com/TrjMJq)